# MessageBox shows more messages than required

Tags: vb.net, loops

The question provided is:

> Write a program that will find and display the smallest, largest and
>   average values in a collection of n numbers, Your program should start
>   by asking how many numbers are to be input before reading each value
>   in the collection of n numbers.

I have done it and it works well, however to finish off requesting the numbers I want to ask the user for the 'last number'. It does this, however when they enter their last number another box shows asking for their 'next number' and then completes the code in question.

In my code, it start asking for the first number, then the next, and then the last. I can't figure out why it's asking for the next number after the last number again. Any help would be useful as neither I nor my tutor can figure out how to fix it.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnGo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click

    Dim TotalNumbers As Integer
    Dim Number As Long, AverageNum As Long, HighestNum As Long, LowestNum As Long

    TotalNumbers = InputBox("Please enter how many numbers you shall be entering into the input box provided:", "How many numbers?")

    Number = InputBox("Enter the first number:", "Input your numbers")
    LowestNum = Number
    HighestNum = Number

    For InputNumbers = 1 To TotalNumbers
        If Number < LowestNum Then
            LowestNum = Number
        ElseIf Number > HighestNum Then
            HighestNum = Number
        End If
        AverageNum = AverageNum + Number
        If InputNumbers = TotalNumbers - 1 Then
            Number = InputBox("Enter the last number:", "Input your numbers")
        Else
            Number = InputBox("Enter the next number:", "Input your numbers")
        End If

    Next
    MessageBox.Show("The highest number entered was: " & HighestNum)
    MessageBox.Show("The lowest number entered was: " & LowestNum)
    MessageBox.Show("The average number entered was: " & AverageNum / TotalNumbers)
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop will run over all the numbers from 1 to TotalNumbers; since you are collecting the first number outside the loop this will be one more iteration than you need. You need to run the loop from 2 to TotalNumbers, since you already have the first, and then use the alternative text when InputNumbers is TotalNumbers, not TotalNumbers - 1. Since you'll then need to repeat the calculation code after the loop to get the final result, you'd probably be better off recasting it to something like this:

```
For InputNumbers = 1 To TotalNumbers
    ' choose the input box text here; First, Next or Last
    ' get the input value
    ' then perform the calculations after the input, in the loop
Next InputNumbers
```

Answer (score 1):

Because, 
     For `InputNumbers = 1` To `TotalNumbers`  is same as  `for(InputNumbers=1;InputNumbers<=TotalNumbers;InputNumbers++)` .
That is, the **loop** will be executing even when `InputNumbers = TotalNumbers.` Loop will be exiting only when `InputNumbers > TotalNumbers.` So last iteration **InputNumbers** value is equal to TotalNumbers.

`" If InputNumbers = TotalNumbers - 1 Then "`   this condition is executing second last time and once more the **loop** will be executing that time else part will be get executed. 
Therefore, Give this condition like this,(so that, last time it will not execute Else part)

```
        If InputNumbers = TotalNumbers - 1 Then
            Number = InputBox("Enter the last number:", "Input your numbers")
        Else If InputNumbers <> TotalNumbers
            Number = InputBox("Enter the next number:", "Input your numbers")
        End If
```